# Re-validating whole entity in a callback with additional groups

Tags: symfony, validation

In Symfony 3 it's no longer possible to re-validate whole entity with dynamic groups in a callback, like this:

```
$executionContext->validate($this, '', 'someGroup', true);
```

How to do it in version 3?

Answer (score 0):

There is a need to get validator and set it context to current one

```
public function validatePrice(ExecutionContextInterface $executionContext)
{
    if($this->type !== self::TYPE_FREE){
        $executionContext
            ->getValidator()
            ->inContext($executionContext)
            ->validate($this, null, ['payableTask'] );
    }
}
```